# How to parse external JSON file in the .jsx file

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm new with React and need some one with my json file Parsing problem. I am having a PerfCompare.jsx with a variable needed in the following compare. And i need this var parsing from a external JSON file(trscConfig.JSON). I am using this lines to do. but always get this SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
[trscConfig.JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZEJZ.png)

```
{
     "server" : "http://myserver.com"
}
```

[PerfCompare.jsx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4tuX.png)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Input, Button, Radio, Row, Table, Divider, Progress, Alert } from 'antd';
import math from 'mathjs';
import { stringify } from 'qs';
import PerffarmRunJSON from './lib/PerffarmRunJSON';
import JenkinsRunJSON from './lib/JenkinsRunJSON';
import benchmarkVariantsInfo from './lib/benchmarkVariantsInfo';
import './PerfCompare.css';

//import App_DATA from './trscConfig.JSON';

const server_2 = JSON.parse('./trscConfig.JSON').server;
```

Comment: Please replace the images by inserting the code directly to the question

Comment: got it done~Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```js
const response = await fetch('trscConfig.JSON');
const json = await response.json();
const server_2 = json.server;
```

Or, if your build tool doesn't support `await` yet:

```js
fetch('trscConfig.JSON')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    const server_2 = json.server;
  });
```

In either case, downloading the JSON file at runtime will mean the response will not be available immediately. If this is a React component, I suggest doing this in `componentDidMount()`.

---

Alternatively, if the JSON file is a static asset:

```js
import {server as server_2} from './trscConfig.JSON';
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but when i try this, it gives: Parsing error: await is a reserved word

Comment: What are you using to transpile your JavaScript? In any case, I've added an await-less version to my answer. The two are equivalent

Comment: import {server as server_2} from './trscConfig.JSON';
It works. OMG just one line of code and stuck for 2 days.

Comment: Good to hear! Usually JSON would come from APIs (not static) so asynchronous fetching/parsing would be needed

Comment: By the way could you accept my answer if it helped?

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` doesn't know how to make HTTP requests/read files - it just parses exactly what you've passed in. In this case, it's failing because it's trying to convert the literal string `./trscConfig.JSON` into a JSON object!

There's two ways you could get this working:

- Load in the JSON via your module bundler, as you're doing in the commented out line in your code. I believe Webpack (and most others) support this out of the box, but your configuration might have it disabled, intentionally or otherwise. It might also be because you're using uppercase file extensions - try it with a file that has `.json` in lowercase.
- Use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), or a third-party HTTP client library to download the JSON at runtime, and then parse the downloaded text.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. right now i'm confused. I changed to the lowecase json and tried to import trscConfig.json file, like below:
    import APP_DATA from './trscConfig.json';
so what i'm gonna do next then.